# What is the source of this female terminator image?

Tags: the-terminator-series

[image]

What is the source of this female terminator image?

Comment: Which source does this remain terminator what? Come from?

Comment: Do terminators have gender?

Comment: They do have gender. Many have male disguises, then here's at least one female one: https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/Cameron. The ones that use the Mimetic polyalloy can be either male or female

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is an [original artwork by Alex Pascenko](https://sideshow.com/blog/alex-pascenko-activates-the-rebel-terminator-mythos-premium-art-print/), licensed by StudioCanal and marketed by [Sideshow Collectibles](https://www.sideshow.com/blog/rise-against-skynet-with-the-rebel-terminator-mythos-premium-format-figure/).

> Sideshow is proud to present the **Rebel Terminator- Mythos** Premium Art
> Print by Alex Pascenko. As a collection, Sideshow’s Mythos series
> captures the limitless possibility of fan-favorite franchises by
> emphasizing core themes and introducing unique story details to
> popular fictional universes.

It was also made available as a [3D model](https://www.sideshow.com/whats-new/rebel-terminator-premium-format-figure/) for fans with too much money on their hands.

[image]

Comment: Both the print and the statuette were made by a company called Sideshow Collectibles which specializes in statues of genre characters (judging by the [prices](https://www.sideshow.com/collectibles/terminator-t-800-darkside-collectibles-studio-911091?var=9110912) of models currently on sale, I don't think they're 3D printed--the bottom of the article on "Rebel Terminator" [here](https://www.sideshow.com/blog/rise-against-skynet-with-the-rebel-terminator-mythos-premium-format-figure/) says it'll go for $560). I would assume the print was made to promote the statue.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - lol. Far too much money on their hands.